# Calling method on method in C++

Tags: c++

in the method `bool Foam::pimpleControl::criteriaSatisfied()` of an OpenFoam Source Code I found the following expression:

```
bool Foam::pimpleControl::criteriaSatisfied()
{
    // ...
    const word& variableName = iter().keyword();
    // ...
}
```

For `iter()` I found:
`Foam::label` `iter()` const inline
Return const access to the current cloud iteration

For `keyword()`:

`keyType& keyword() inline`
Return non-const access to keyword.

I have two questions about this:

1. What does it mean when calling method on method like `iter().keyword();`?
2. What does `&` after `word&` or `keyType&` mean? I know that every method also has a datatyp declaration, but has the `&` a specific meaning?

greetings Streight

Comment: "Foam::label iter() const inline Return const access to the current cloud iteration" - Come again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does it mean when calling method on method like `iter().keyword();`

`iter()` returns an object. `keyword()` then calls a method of that object. It's basically just a shorthand for `Foam::label temp = iter(); temp.keyword()`.

> What does & after word& or keyType& mean?

The ampersand is part of the type. `const word&` names the type "reference to `const word`".

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling a "method on method". "iter()" is returning an object and that object has a member "keyword()".

The code is equivalent to

```
Foam::label& it = iter();
it.keyword();
```

here's a simplified example:

```
class A {
    int m_i;
public:
    A(int i) : m_i(i) {}
    int GetI() const { return m_i; }
};

class B {
    A m_a;
public:
    B(int i) : m_a(i) {}
    const A& GetA() const { return m_a; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    B b(42);

    const A& a = b.GetA();
    std::cout << "a.GetI() == " << a.GetI() <<std::endl;

    // above code is directly equivalent to:
    std::cout << "b.GetA().GetI() == " << b.GetA().GetI() <<std::endl;
}
```

In the last line, "b.GetA()" returns a temporary, anonymous "const A&" object, and then we call "GetI()" on that object.

Comment: Thx for the example, I just gave the other answer the solved flag, because it appeared first and also answered my question.